self-contained WinRT IBackgroundTask
I followed Microsoft documentation and created working WinRT IBackgroundTask that runs on dotnet8. Now I want to integrate it with my app which is deployed as self-contained and it doesn't require framework deployment for dotnet 8. I tried to modify WinRT.Host.runtimeconfig.json from this
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net8.0",
    "rollForward": "LatestMinor",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "8.0.0"
    }
  }
}

to this
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net8.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "8.0.3"
      }
    ],
  }
}

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?
I see this in event viewer
Application: backgroundTaskHost.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.324.11423
.NET Version: 8.0.3
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080204)
   at MobiSystems.BackgroundTasks.CheckForUpdates.CheckForUpdatesBackgroundTask.RunExecutionAlias()
   at MobiSystems.BackgroundTasks.CheckForUpdates.CheckForUpdatesBackgroundTask.Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()


It is not supported see here: https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/1141
Microsoft doesn't provide framework package for .net core and tell us to use self-contained deployments for packaged apps but also don't support features in self-contained app. Priceless.
